# How do passive boosters/repeaters (such as a HDMI 'booster') work?

Tags: signal-integrity, hdmi

I have a HDMI device and I want to connect it to something very far away. I notice you can buy a HDMI booster to do this, but some of them are unpowered (they take no external power). How can a signal be boosted in this way without external power?

Comment: Hdmi has a 5v power line on it. 50mA by spec but many are not current limited.

Comment: Do all devices put out 5v to their HDMI out? For example my computer?

Comment: Yes, all HDMI outputs must have 5V supply.

Comment: I'm not good enough to offer this as an authoritative answer, but if you're talking about something like redmere cables, I believe a bank of mosfets are used to stiffen up the edges of the digital signal.  From experience, this type of booster can be better than a powered booster for short runs.  I've had issues that appeared to be the result of a powered amplifier/splitter putting out too strong a signal.